# GlassFish 6.2.1 throws 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jakartaee.jakarta.servlet.ServletContainer' while deploying JAX-RS web service

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rs

I used Jakarta EE 9, glassfish 6.2.1 server and NetBeans 14 to create a restful web service.
Couldn't deploy it as got some errors in the log file of Glassfish server.
The error was :
"  [2023-06-01T14:16:12.835+0530] [glassfish 6.2] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1685609172835] [levelValue: 900] [[
Mapping conflict. A Servlet registration exists with same mapping as the Jersey servlet application, named com.ayush1.server.MyApplication, at the servlet mapping, /api/*.]]

[2023-06-01T14:16:12.840+0530] [glassfish 6.2] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1685609172840] [levelValue: 800] [[
WebModule[/rest2] ServletContext.log():Marking servlet jakarta-servlet as unavailable]]

[2023-06-01T14:16:12.841+0530] [glassfish 6.2] [SEVERE] [] [jakarta.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1685609172841] [levelValue: 1000] [[
WebModule[/rest2]Error loading WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) org.glassfish.jakartaee.jakarta.servlet.ServletContainer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jakartaee.jakarta.servlet.ServletContainer
"
"[2023-06-01T14:16:12.843+0530] [glassfish 6.2] [SEVERE] [] [jakarta.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1685609172843] [levelValue: 1000] [[
WebModule[/rest2]Servlet &#x2f;rest2 threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jakartaee.jakarta.servlet.ServletContainer"

"
[2023-06-01T14:16:12.852+0530] [glassfish 6.2] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00108] [jakarta.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1685609172852] [levelValue: 1000] [[
ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jakartaee.jakarta.servlet.ServletContainer
"
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdMMM.png

[java class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDs59.png)

[Myapplication class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtqJX.png)

[web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btLq9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` elements from your web.xml file. They conflict with the REST servlet created by GlassFish when your app is deployed.